# Laravel 4 to 5 Pagination Conversion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination, laravel-5

Im looking to change the Pagination from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5, I've Solved the issue of me using a Custom Driver so I am able to use Cache:tags for files

i need to change this code to Laravel 5:

```
public function buildPaginateQuery(array $params, $page = 1, $perPage = 15)
{
    $query = $this->model->table == 'links' ? $this->model->with('Title') : $this->model;

    $query = $this->appendParams($params, $query);

    $count = $query->cacheTags('count')->remember(2000)->count();

    $totalPages = $count / $perPage;

    $query = $query->skip($perPage * ($page - 1))->take($perPage);

    $query = $query->order(isset($params['order']) && $params['order'] ? $params['order'] : null);

    $query = $query->cacheTags(array($this->model->table, 'pagination'))->remember(2000);

    return array('query' => $query, 'totalPages' => $totalPages, 'totalItems' => $count);
}
```

I tried doing it myself but I do not know how, The code below is what I've done so far, but when i use it it gives this error:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Current Attempted Code:

```
/**
 * Builds paginate query with given parameters.
 * 
 * @param  array   $params
 * @param  integer $page
 * @param  integer $perPage
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function buildPaginateQuery(array $params, $page = 1, $perPage = 15)
{
    $query = $this->model->table == 'links' ? $this->model->with('Title') : $this->model;

    $query = $this->appendParams($params, $query);

    $count = Cache::remember('count', 2000, function() use ($query)
            {
                return $query->count();
            });

    $totalPages = $count / $perPage;

    $query = $query->skip($perPage * ($page - 1))->take($perPage);

    $query = $query->order(isset($params['order']) && $params['order'] ? $params['order'] : null);

    $query = Cache::tags([$this->model->table, 'pagination'])->remember('pagination', 2000, function() use ($query)
            {
                return $query;
            });

    return array('query' => $query, 'totalPages' => $totalPages, 'totalItems' => $count);
}
```

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: on th line that contains      `$query = Cache::tags([$this->model->table, 'pagination'])->remember('pagination', 2000, function() use ($query)
            {
                return $query;
            });`